# React.js, how to avoid var me = this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding, this

wondering about the best way to avoid using var me = this; in the following context. This method exists inside of a React component. I have used the underscore.js method _.bind() in the past - is there a more reacty way?

```
    findRoutes: function(){
        var me = this;
        if (!this.state.originId || !this.state.destinationId) {
            alert("findRoutes!");
            return;
        }
        var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            directionsService.route({
                origin: {'placeId': me.state.originId},
                destination: {'placeId': me.state.destinationId},
                travelMode: me.state.travelMode
            }, function(response, status){
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    // me.response = response;
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    resolve(response);
                } else {
                    window.alert('Directions config failed due to ' + status);
                }
            });
        });
        return p1
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preserving the correct `this` is more a JavaScript problem than React.

1) One option is to use the [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method:

```
 findRoutes: function(){
        if (!this.state.originId || !this.state.destinationId) {
            alert("findRoutes!");
            return;
        }
        var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            directionsService.route({
                origin: {'placeId': this.state.originId},
                destination: {'placeId': this.state.destinationId},
                travelMode: this.state.travelMode
            }, function(response, status){
               //...
            });
        }.bind(this)); // <----------- .bind(this)
        return p1
    },
```

The `.bind(this)` will create a new function that has the same `this` as the `findRoutes()` function.

2) Another option from ES6 is the [arrow function](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilx_yxmPLMAhXMcBoKHWbqBxsQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions%2FArrow_functions&usg=AFQjCNEJ7j1iiQ3p-iy7u9L78rzUyEGUHg&sig2=kbyLH0PUW_v3z5otkhcBTw&bvm=bv.122676328,d.d24):

```
 findRoutes: function(){
        if (!this.state.originId || !this.state.destinationId) {
            alert("findRoutes!");
            return;
        }
        var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <------- used =>
            directionsService.route({
                origin: {'placeId': this.state.originId},
                destination: {'placeId': this.state.destinationId},
                travelMode: this.state.travelMode
            }, function(response, status){
               //...
            });
        });
        return p1
    },
```

The arrow function will take lexically `this` from the `findRoutes()`.

[See this article](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/) for more details about `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

My tip to avoid the need of referencing this on the context is start using [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#Constants)'s [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

So you could use a arrow function as the promise callback.

```
let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(this.state)
})
```

The best way in my opinion of using ES6 in your React project is using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for compiling the ES6 code and [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) for module bundling.

Here is a good example of project to start using webpack and babel:

https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which provide lexical binding to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) value